# Was meinen wir eigentlich mit "eigentlich"?

Tags: word-usage, adjective, adverb, particle

Das Wort *"eigentlich"* wird sehr häufig und in vielfältigster Weise eingesetzt:

> **Eigentlich** sollten Sie diese Arbeit doch schon bis gestern erledigt haben.
>   Kommt Ihr **eigentlich** morgen zu unserer Party?
>   **Eigentlich** habe ich das nicht so gemeint.
>   Bist Du **eigentlich** zufrieden mit Deinem Leben?
>   Wann ist **eigentlich** der nächste Feiertag?
>   Der **eigentliche** Name des Benutzers "Quatschmaus" ist Müller.
>   "Quatschmaus" heißt **eigentlich** Müller im richtigen Leben.

Bei vielen dieser Beispiele könnte man *"eigentlich"* aber eigentlich auch weglassen, ohne dass sich dadurch die eigentliche Bedeutung wesentlich änderte.

Was möchten wir ausdrücken, wenn wir *"eigentlich"* benutzen? Ist die Verwendung von *"eigentlich"* überhautp guter Stil oder handelt es sich eher um Umgangssprache?

Comment: Wie kann man eigentlich die Frage schon in der Frage beantworten? ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

„Eigentlich“ ist nicht Umgangssprache. Es gibt je nach Situation einem Satz eine andere Betonung, eine andere Note.

Die Behauptung, man könne das Wort einfach weglassen (reines, überflüssiges Füllwort), ist so nicht haltbar. Schauen wir uns den ersten Satz an:

> Eigentlich sollten Sie diese Arbeit doch schon bis gestern erledigt haben.

Er lässt sich verkürzen auf:

> Sie sollten diese Arbeit bis gestern erledigt haben.

Auch „doch“ und „schon“ fallen hier raus. Sie sind ähnlich „überflüssig“ wie „eigentlich“. In diesem Satz verstärken aber alle drei Wörter den Vorwurf, dass die Arbeit noch nicht erledigt ist. Würde ich den Satz in einem Roman verwenden, überlegte ich mir, ob ich wirklich alle drei Verstärkungswörter verwendete; aber auf alle verzichten würde ich nicht.

Zur eigentlichen Anwendung von „eigentlich“:

1) Es kann als [Adjektiv](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eigentlich_tatsaechlich_echt) verwendet werden:

> Der eigentliche Name des Benutzers „Quatschmaus“ ist Müller.

Hier wird der tatsächliche Sachverhalt betont. (Merke: tatsächlich ist „tatsächlich“ hier eigentlich ein Synonym für „eigentlich“ (wenn ich jetzt nicht alle Nicht-Muttersprachler verwirrt habe, wann dann :)))
Es wird betont: Quatschmaus ist nicht der richtige Name.

2) Es kann als [Adverb](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eigentlich_wirklich_urspruenglich) verwendet werden (wie fast alle Adjektive):

> Eigentlich habe ich das nicht so gemeint.

Wieder eine Betonung – hier wird der Unterschied zum äußeren Anschein klar gemacht. (Allerdings wird dies heutzutage nur als halbherziger Einwand wahrgenommen, da es schon millionenfach einfach nur so dahingesagt wurde.)

3) Es kann als [Partikel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eigentlich_ueberhaupt_uebrigens) verwendet werden:

> Kommt Ihr eigentlich morgen zu unserer Party?

Als Partikel verstärkt oder relativiert es Fragesätze (jedenfalls fallen mir nur Fragesätze ein). Die Frage klingt hier beiläufig. Es wird versucht, sie nicht fordernd/befehlend klingen zu lassen.
Man merkt das gut im direkten Vergleich:

> Kommt Ihr endlich mal zu einer unserer Partys?

In dieser Konstruktion ist ein direkter Vorwurf impliziert. Dieser wird mit „eigentlich“ vermieden.

Comment: Der Vollständigkeit halber sollte ich noch [uneigentlich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/uneigentlich_ungenau) erwähnen :)

Comment: Bei `Sie sollten die Arbeit schon gestern erledigt haben` wirkt `eigentlich` m.E. abschwächend, nicht verstärkend. Man öffnet schon schon die Tür zur Ausrede `... , wäre da nicht der Termin XY noch reinkommen`.

Comment: @user unknown: Ist das eigentlich so? "Sie sollten diese Arbeit bis gestern erledigt haben" (also ohne "eigentlich" stellt für mich eigentlich noch keinen Vorwurf dar - Es ist einfach eine Feststellung ohne Wertung. Erst das "eigentlich" macht es dazu.

Comment: @fofro: Wohl eine Frage der Betonung… Ich nehme aber jetzt keine mp3-Datei auf, abgesehen davon, dass das auch gar nicht unterstützt wird, hier. :)

Comment: Ich finde die klaren Definitionen hier schwierig. Es ist immer eine Frage der Betonung und des Kontexts. Z.B. kann "Eigentlich habe ich das nicht so gemeint." auch implizieren, dass man es erst nicht so meinte, jetzt aber schon.

Answer (score 3):

Eigentlich ist die Frage ja schon beantwortet. Aber ich denke, dass doch noch ein Aspekt unberücksichtigt gelassen wurde: Nämlich, dass zumindest in Aussagesätzen ein „eigentlich“ in der Regel (wenn nicht sogar immer) ein „aber“ impliziert.

Nehmen wir zum Beispiel an, ich habe ein Programm, und will damit eine bestimmte Datei öffnen, was fehlschlägt. Deshalb rufe ich den Support an.

**Fall 1:** Der Support erklärt mir:

> Dieses Dateiformat wird vom Programm nicht unterstützt.

Damit ist klar: Ich habe keine Chance, die Datei zu öffnen. Oder zumindest werde ich vom Support nicht erfahren, wie es geht.

**Fall 2:** Der Support erklärt mir:

> Eigentlich wird dieses Dateiformat vom Programm nicht unterstützt.

Dann weiß ich: Mit Tricks könnte ich das Programm vielleicht doch noch dazu überreden, die Datei zu öffnen. Und höchstwahrscheinlich lautet dann der nächste Satz:

> Aber Sie können ja mal versuchen, dies und jenes zu machen.

Ein sehr gutes Beispiel für den engen Zusammenhang von "eigentlich" und "aber" ist auch der berüchtigte Satz:

> Eigentlich habe ich ja nichts gegen [Randgruppe], aber …