# Was genau bezeichnet das Wort Statussymbol?

Tags: meaning

Muss ein Statussymbol offen zur Schau getragen werden, muss eine Kommunikationsabsicht bestehen, damit etwas zum Statussymbol wird?

Beispielsweise ist bei einer teuren Armbanduhr relativ klar, dass die (auch) ein Statussymbol ist. Wikipedia [listet](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statussymbol) auch das Beispiel der Irokesenfrisur, die Symbol für den Status als Punk ist.

Was ist aber mit Dingen, die niemand sieht - Seidenunterhemden etwa. Sind das Statussymbole?

Und wie sieht es aus mit Dingen, die zwar sichtbar sind, aber gar nicht in der Absicht genutzt werden, auf den eigenen Status hinzuweisen? Aktuelles Beispiel sind Smartphones. Die Welt am Sonntag beispielsweise [ist der Meinung](http://www.welt.de/print/wams/wirtschaft/article13761596/Das-Smartphone-ist-nicht-aufzuhalten.html), Smartphones seien Statussymbole, weil Smartphonebesitz mit Einkommen und Gehalt korreliert. Wenn nun jemand sein Smartphone gekauft hat, weil er es braucht oder praktisch oder schön findet, ihm aber sein Status völlig egal ist - dies also die Kaufentscheidung nicht beeinflusst hat - ist das dann ein Statussymbol?

Zusammengefasst: Ist "Statussymbol" nur ein anderes Wort für "Statusindikator", oder steckt im Statussymbol eine Kommunikationsabsicht - oder ist es sogar völlig anders als von mir vermutet?

Comment: Ist das nicht eher eine die kulturelle Ebene betreffende Frage, die relativ wenig mit der deutschen Sprache per se zu tun hat? So trefflich sich darüber auch parlieren lässt, möchte ich mit anderen Worten fragen: Gehört die Frage überhaupt hierhin?

Comment: Verständliche Frage, aber es geht mir schon um die Bedeutung des Wortes.

Answer (score 4):

Zur Bedeutung von ***"Statussymbol"*** kann man getrost die Erklärung, die Duden und DWDS liefern, zitieren, die zwar knapp aber präzise den Sinn diesen Wortes wiedergeben:

> etwas, was jemandes gehobenen Status dokumentieren soll<sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Statussymbol)</sup>
>
> Besitz oder Verhalten, die das soziale Prestige eines Menschen in den Augen seiner Umwelt ausmachen (Mitte 20. Jh.), nach amerik.-engl. *status symbol*.<sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Statussymbol&view=1)</sup>

Interssant ist, dass laut DWDS auch das Verhalten - also nicht nur ein materieller Besitz -Symbolcharakter haben kann. Dies beinhaltet nämlich auch, dass man ein Statussymbol nicht unbedingt offen zeigen muss (siehe Seidenunterwäsche).

Demnach kann die als Besipiel aus Wikipedia genannte Irokesenfrisur zwar ein Symbol für den Status *"Punk*" sein, weil damit aber kein **gehobener Status** symbolisiert wird, wäre die Bezeichnung *"Statussymbol"* hier irreführend (wenn auch aus der Sicht der Punks vielleicht passend). *"Statusindikator"*, wäre hier besser, wenn es dieses Wort denn gäbe.

Was genau die gegenwärtige Gesellschaft (oder Gruppe innerhalb einer Gesellschaft) als *Statussymbol* ansieht (und was nicht), ist weniger eine sprachliche als ein soziologische Frage, zumal dies einem gehörigen Maß an Wandel unterzogen ist (vergleiche Rundfunkempfänger, Fernseher, Mobiltelefon, Laptop und nun ist das Smartphone gerade dabei seinen Statussymbolcharakter zu verlieren).

Comment: Auch @Splattne und Thomas: Das heißt also, dass etwas (eine Sache oder ein Sachverhalt oder auch ein Verhalten) erst durch (evtl. unterbewusste) Intention zum Statussymbol wird? Ein nützlicher Gegenstand ist also nicht *per se* Statussymbol, sondern wird erst durch den Besitzer dazu gemacht? (Gut, ein schweizer Chronograph ist meist nicht *besser* als eine japanische Digitaluhr - und kann somit wahrscheinlich fast nur als Statussymbol verwendet werden. Aber z. B. ein teurer, schneller Computer mag für den einen Notwendigkeit, für den anderen Statussymbol sein?)

Comment: [Eigentlich](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3134/23) ist im Einzelfalls ein Statussymbol eine höchst **subjektive** Sache. Was dem einen wie eins erscheint, ist dem anderen möglicherweise nur ein alltäglicher Gebrauchsgegenstand. Die Grenzen sind hier fließend. Nur am oberen Ende (Jacht, Ferrari, Schmuck) wird es eindeutig.

Comment: Denke auch bei Irokesenfrisur wäre eher *Alleinstellungsmerkmal/Erkennungsmerkmal* besser angebracht. Wer sich Calvin Klein Unterwäsche leisten kann (und sie auch täglich wechselt :)) oder seine Firma mit Apple Produkten komplett ausstattet, möchte aber mit diesen Gebrauchsgegenständen dann doch auch Eindruck schinden. Ein Alleinstellungsmerkmal (Marke/Preis) ist aber erstmal per se kein hinreichender Faktor für ein Statussymbol, sonst müsste man ja alle Sammlerstücke als Statussymbole bezeichnen

Comment: @Hauser Ich möchte Dir im Einzelfall widersprechen. Ich nutze bspw. einen Apple-Computer und ein Apple-Smartphone. Manche Leute - unter Anderem Du - unterstellen mir nun, ich täte dies, um damit Eindruck zu schinden. Will ich aber gar nicht. Die Sachen sind halt gut. Und zugegebenermaßen auch schick und teuer. Sind es nun Statussymbole, weil Du denkst, ich besitze die, weil ich damit angeben will, oder sind es keine, weil ich mich darüber ärgere, dass Du das denkst, und ich den Kram nur habe, weil ich ihn tatsächlich besser finde als die Alternativen?

Comment: @ fzwo: oft noch etwas subtiler: ob etwas ein Statussymbol ist wird möglicherweise erst durch die Wahrnehmung anderer entschieden. Das heisst es kann sein, dass nicht der Besitzer es dazu macht (der kann es auch tun, indem er es besonders hervorhebt, etwa indem er auf der Anrede 'Herr Dr.' besteht oder dafür sorgt, dass die teure Uhr gut sichtbar ist), sondern z.B. auch der Neider sich einen Mercedes kauft, weil der Nachbar einen hat. Auch die Presse kann etwas zu einem Statussymbol machen.

Comment: @fzwo Mir ist es real schon aufgefallen, dass Firmen (Anwälte/Designer/Marketing) Büros teuer mit stylischen Mac's ausstatten, wo dann windows Office drauf läuft, alles in gediegenen umgebenden Mobiliar, eben auch um sich von ordinären Firmen hier abzuheben ("Die scheinen erfolgreich zu sein!") Ich hab selber nen Ipod, ist kein Statussymbol für mich. Aber Apple ist gutes Beispiel, für viele einfach praktische Geräte, für manche aber eben mehr als Gebrauchsgegenstand sondern oft auch elitäres Gruppenmerkmal in best. Cliquen wie eben auch Kleidung/Automarke...

Comment: "Wenn du kein Iphone hast, hast du kein Iphone" trägt leider gezielt dazu bei, das gehört mit zu Marketingstrategie von Apple, das kannst du vermeintlich nicht nur den Neidern in die Schuhe schieben

Comment: @Hauser: Klar, einige Leute benutzen Macs als Statussymbole. Oder Mercedesse. Das war genau der Inhalt meiner Frage: *Sind* es Statussymbole, selbst für die, die z. B. einen Mac oder Mercedes besitzen, weil sie - beispielsweise - die Zuverlässigkeit schätzen? Also: Wer macht ein Statussymbol zum Statussymbol - oder ist es gar eine inhärente Eigenschaft mancher Produkte?

Answer (score 4):

Meiner Einschätzung nach wird ein Objekt (oder ein Titel oder Mitgliedschaft eines elitären Vereins) oder eine Klasse von Objekten als Statussymbol bezeichnet, wenn es nachweislich öffentlich bei/an der Besitzerin gesehen wird (implizit) oder wenn es vom Eigentümer zur Schau gestellt wird (explizit).

Statussymbole sind häufig Luxusobjekte wie zum Beispiel teure Markenuhren, die das oberste Preissegment einer Kategorie von Artikeln darstellen.

Weitere typische Statussymbole können zum Beispiel sein:

- Luxuswagen bestimmten Marken
- Yacht
- Küchen bestimmter Marken
- Villa
- Golfclubmitgliedschaft

Ob eine Person-Statussymbol-Relation besteht, hängt auch davon ab, ob die Person für den Verwendungszweck eine Alternative hat oder nicht. Wenn zum Beispiel jemand, der Bootsausflüge für betuchte Menschen unternimmt, eine Yacht besitzt, dann kann man hier nicht von einem Statussymbol sprechen.

Comment: "Mein Auto, meine Yacht, mein Haus", welche dusslige Werbung war das gleich noch mal? Fällt mir nicht mehr ein

Comment: @Hauser Sparkasse: "Mein Haus, mein Auto, mein Boot" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0MU-2_MuUE

Comment: Und wenn sich jemand einen Mercedes kaufte, weil er ein gut ausgestattetes, sicheres Auto haben will und die Sitze bequem findet? Wäre das ein Statussymbol? Müsste er den Stern abkleben, damit's keins mehr wäre?

Answer (score 3):

Ergänzend zu den bereits vorliegenden Antorten würde ich noch anmerken, dass die Frage, was ein Statussymbol ist, oft sehr stark von der Perspektive abhängt, auch wenn es im Grossen und Ganzen einen gesellschaftlichen Konsens geben mag. So mag es in der Tat Leute geben, die ein Smartphone besitzen, ohne es als Statussymbol wahr zu nehmen. Gleichzeitig kann eine andere Person, die das Smartphone im Besitz der ersten Person wahr nimmt, es als Statussymbol interpretieren. Das geht auch umgekehrt. Das hängt jeweils von der Einstellung der betroffenen Personen ab.