# "Eigentlich" benutzen

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Meine Deutschlehrerin meint, dass man das Wort "eigentlich" nicht benutzen muss.

Ich übersetze "*eigentlich*" zu "*actually*". Aber sie sagte tatsächlich sei ein besseres Wort.

Gibt es keine Beispielsätze, in denen das Wort "*eigentlich*" richtig benutzt ist?

Mein Beispiel:

> Hast du das verstanden?
>
> Eigentlich ja. (Ich weiß dass es ein falsches Beispiel ist)

PS: Wenn die Frage kein Sinn macht, könnte ich die auf Englisch übersetzen.

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/was-meinen-wir-eigentlich-mit-eigentlich

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the body of your question, I get the impression it is very much about understanding your teacher’s comments and translating *actually*, so I want to help with this part, which seems not to have been covered yet. The second part of my answer treats *eigentlich* in some detail.

### Understanding your teacher’s comments

The fundamental meaning of *actually* (which is close to factually) is well translated by *tatsächlich*.

> We must pay attention to what customers are actually buying/Wir müssen beachten, was die Kunden tatsächlich kaufen

But beyond that, *actually* is used in several other ways. That’s where the overlap with *eigentlich* occurs! Consider this:

> Wussten Sie eigentlich, daß er verheiratet ist?/Did you actually know that he is married?

Many such occurrences of *eigentlich* and similar terms are regarded as fillers and discouraged by traditional teachers, but of course they are a legitimate part of colouring speech, creating pauses etc. Still traditional teachers may be right to discourage use of fillers in the early stages of learning.

### Understanding *eigentlich*

#### Fundamental meanings

The fundamental meaning of *eigentlich* is  *proper*, *true*, *original* and thus harks back to *eigen* (own, characteristic, peculiar). Hence the mathematical term:

> uneigentliches Integral/improper integral

Note that ethical impropriety cannot be described with this term! Consider this:

> Er heißt eigentlich Archibald Alec Leach, nennt sich aber Cary/He was in fact (originally) named Archibald Alec Leach, but calls himself Cary.
>
> Eigentlich hast du recht/strictly speaking (in principle, fundamentally....) you are right
>
> Eigentlich wollten wir in Griechenland Urlaub machen. Nun kam die Stromrechnung und wir bleiben in Kleinküttlach/Originally we meant to go on vacation in Greece. Now the electricity bill arrived and we‘re staying in Little Droppington.

#### Accentuating or filler meanings

In many cases *eigentlich* works like words that  change the mood of the sentence, especially [modal particles,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_modal_particles) such as *denn*. This is why you think of it as a [Flickwort](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Flickwort).

> Wie spät ist es eigentlich ~ wie spät ist es denn/How late (what time) is it

The modal shift above is not exactly translatable, but I would argue it is close to *anyway*. *Eigentlich* can transport an accusing tone as well:

> Bist du eigentlich noch bei Troste?/Are you crazy?

I can’t think of an English equivalent. *Eigentlich* can be used to add a certain casual/in passing tone:

> Hat sie eigentlich einen Freund?/Does she have a boyfriend?

In the context of modal changes **your example is most definitely not wrong**. If the professor doesn’t have faith in his student and the student wants to soften her claim, we could very well witness the exchange

> Hast du das verstanden?
>
> Eigentlich ja

Comment: Gerade beim Vorwurf kann das Wort "eigentlich" tatsächlich (sic!) eine Doppelfunktion als Füllwort und Bedeutungsträger haben: "Weißt Du eigentlich, wie spät es ist?!". Ohne das "eigentlich" könnte man nur noch am Tonfall unterscheiden, ob es ein Vorwurf oder eine ernstgemeinte Frage nach der Zeit ist.

Comment: @Volker stimmt. Vielleicht sollte man den Begriff “Flickwort” gar nicht einbauen. Es wurde aber in der Frage erwähnt. Vorschläge?

Comment: abgesehen davon, dass der mir vertraute Begriff "Füllwort" ist und ich "Flickwort" bisher nicht kannte (sicherlich eine Frage der Region, in der man lebt), nein, kein anderer Vorschlag. Mein Kommentar war auch nicht als Korrektur/Widerspruch gemeint, sondern als Ergänzung :-)

Comment: @Volker Das gilt auch für mich. Ich bilde mir ein „Flickwort“ habe in der Frage gestanden. Jetzt steht es dort allerdings nicht mehr...

Comment: vielen Dank für die Erklärung.

Comment: @Volker: Das ist falsch. "Weißt **Du** eigentlich wie spät es ist" ändert den Sinn der Frage ebenso.

Comment: @user unknown: Wenn es eine Frage-Weiterleitung ist (egal ob ich selbst von jemand anderem gefragt wurde und verneinen musste oder ob ich gerade den x-ten frage) würde ich dabei definitiv das Wort "eigentlich" **nicht** benutzen

Comment: @Volker: Trinktour, 2 Freunde im Park, irgendwann zwischen 3 und 5 Uhr morgens. Einer hält sich die leere Flasche wie ein Mikro vor den Mund und beginnt sehr laut zu singen. Der andere: "Weißt Du eigentlich, wie spät es ist?" Der andere: "He, es ist Freitag, nein Samstag, die Leute können ausschlafen. Außerdem ist das nächste Haus 500 m weit weg. Siehst Du hier irgendwo Cops? Weißt *Du* eigentlich wie spät es ist?"

Answer (score 6):

Das Wort *eigentlich* ist dort sinnvoll, wo es seine Aufgabe als Adjektiv erfüllt und sich auf das bezieht, was der betreffenden Sache *eigen* ist:

> - Die *eigentliche* Frage lautet doch ...
> - die *eigentliche* Bedeutung des Wortes

Das Adjektiv *tatsächlich* betont, dass die Sache zuvor nicht den Tatsachen entsprochen habe:

> - Die *tatsächliche* Frage lautet hingegen ...
>     
>   <sup>(Zuvor kam eine Frage auf, die mit den Tatsachen nichts zu tun hatte.)</sup>
> - die *tatsächliche* Bedeutung des Wortes
>     
>   <sup>(Zuvor war eine falsche Wortbedeutung im Umlauf.)</sup>

Wo *eigentlich* nicht als Adjektiv, sondern als Adverb oder Partikel verwendet wird, ist es oft überflüssig:

> - *Eigentlich* hab' ich es geahnt.
> - Was willst du *eigentlich* von mir?
> - Das geht *eigentlich* nicht!

Da hilft es auch nicht, es mit einem "besseren" Wort wie *tatsächlich* auszutauschen. Trotzdem gehe ich nicht so weit, den adverbiellen und partikelhaften Gebrauch als umgangssprachlich oder gar falsch zu bezeichnen.

Comment: Die drei letzten Beispiele gefallen mir nicht, denn sie fallen in das gleiche Schema wie die Beispiele darüber: Man hat etwas geahnt aber die Ahnung für sich behalten. Der andere will etwas von Dir, aber was er ausdrückt ist nicht das Eigentliche. So, wie es im dritten Satz gemacht werden soll, entspricht es nicht den Gepflogenheiten, aber wenn man diese missachtet geht es doch.

Comment: Bitte nochmal lesen! In den ersten Beispielen ist _eigentlich_ ein Adjektiv, in den letzten drei Beispielen hingegen nicht, und genau um diesen Unterschied geht es.

Answer (score 3):

Ein Beispiel, wo `eigentlich` aus meiner Sicht auch verwendet werden kann, wäre:

> I don't know him well. I actually don't know him at all.
>   Ich kenne ihn nicht gut. Eigentlich kenne ich ihn gar nicht.

Aber auch das klingt eher "umgangssprachlich". Ich würde das eigentlich übersetzen als:

> Ich kenne ihn nicht gut. Genau genommen kenne ich ihn gar nicht.

In Deinem Beispiel erwartet man jedoch noch ein "aber". "Eigentlich habe ich das verstanden" führt normalerweise sofort zu der Frage, was denn dann das Problem ist.

Comment: Du hast ein "eigentlich" in deine Antowrt :-)

Comment: @Vini Ja, niemand hat gesagt, dass man *eigentlich* nicht sagen darf :-) Wenn Du genau schaust, habe ich davor auch das dazugehörige *aber*. Nur, wenn jemand wissen möchte, ob Du etwas verstanden oder erledigt hast, dann ist "eigentlich" eine Einschränkung und "eigentlich ja" ist näher am "nein" als am "ja".

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Allerdings könnte das *eigentlich ja* sich auch auf ein vom Gegenüber impliziertes *Nein* beziehen. Die verschüchterte Studentin könnte  zum Beispiel so auf die strenge Frage ihrer Professorin antworten.